# how to download a file from given url to buffer with got library?

Tags: node.js

I want to download a file from an url with got library, this is my current code:

```
    var data
    try
    {
        var stream = got.stream (url)
        stream.on ('data', d => data += d)
        stream.end ()
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        console.error (error)
    }
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: The payload has been already provided
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`got.stream()` makes a GET request by default, you need to set `allGetBody` to `true` to avoid the `TypeError`.

So do this instead:

```js
var data
try {
  var stream = got.stream (url, { allowGetBody: true })
  stream.on ('data', d => data += d);
  stream.end()
} catch (error) {
  console.error (error)
}
```

See [Got Documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#body)  on this

Here's a working example on [Javascript Runkit](https://runkit.com/60a3d98deaab4400130208ab/60a3d996765afb001a94bceb)

Comment: i don't remember provide any payload with that got.stream, does got send some payload by default?

Comment: No, it doesn't, my bad! But you have to set that option because you're making a GET request @WilliamTaylor